# Joining separate topics with Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In my current project we have created a data-pipeline using Kafka, Kafka Connect, Elasticsearch. The data ends up on a topic "signal-topic" and is off the form

```
KeyValue<id:String, obj:Signal>
```

Now Im trying to introduce Kafka Streams to be able to do some processing of the data in its way from Kafka to Elasticsearch.

My first goal is to be able to enhance the data with different kinds of side-information. A typical scenario would be to attach another field to the data based on some information already existing in the data. For instance, the data contains a "rawevent"-field and based on that I want to add a "event-description" and then output to a different topic.

What would be the "correct" way of implementing this?

I was thinking of maby having the side-data on a separate 
 topic in kafka

```
KeyValue<rawEvent:String, eventDesc:String>
```

and having streams joining the two topics , but I'm not sure how to accomplish that.
Would this be possible? All examples that I've come across seem to require that the keys of the data-sources would be the same and since mine are'nt I'm not sure its possible.
If anyone have a snippet for how this could be done it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. You can extract`rawEvent` from `Signal` and set as new Key to do the join against a `KTable<rawEvent:String, eventDesc:String>`. Something like `KStream#selectKey(...)#join(KTable...)`
2. You can do KStream-GlobalKTable join: this allows to extract a non-key join attribute from the KStream (in your case `rawEvent`) that is used to do a GlobalKTable lookup to compute the join.

> Note, that both joins do provide different semantics as a KStream-KTable join is synchronized on time, while a KStream-GlobalKTable join is not synchronized. Check out this blog post for more details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/